# Deploying FastAPI Application to K8s

Tags: docker, kubernetes, fastapi, minikube

Currently learning about K8s and FastAPI. I want to deploy an FastAPI application to my Minikube cluster.
If I run the Container it works fine but I can't access it via the the Minikube IP with Port 30001. What did I do wrong?

FastAPI Code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World!"}


@app.get("/hello/{name}")
async def say_hello(name: str):
    return {"message": f"Hello, {name}"}
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9
RUN pip install fastapi uvicorn
COPY ./app /app
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3'
services:
  core-api:
    build: .
    container_name: "fastapi-runtime-container"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: uvicorn app.main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8000
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/app
```

K8s deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: fastapi-app
spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: fastapi-app
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                app: fastapi-app
        spec:
            containers:
                - name: fastapi-app
                  image: luwinkler/fastapi:latest
                  ports:
                      - containerPort: 8000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: fastapi-service
spec:
    type: NodePort
    selector:
        app: fastapi-app
    ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 8000
          targetPort: 8000
          nodePort: 30001
```

The service is running fine according to "kubectl get all", also the pod is running.

I took the IP address from "minikube ip" + port 30001.

Comment: what error is shows? what does kubectl get events show?

Comment: you must use port forwarding to access apps in a cluster.

Comment: No error is shown, simply "the site can't be reached because it took too long to respond.". "kubectl get events" shows no events but this should be normal no?

Shouldn't the nodeport type allow me to access the app in browser? I kinda did it similar to the tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s_o8dwzRlu4
(Minute 59)

Comment: Have you seen https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/ and the steps outlined there? In particular `minikube service hello-minikube1 --url` and the steps around accessing the service?

Comment: `minikube service hello-minikube1 --url` this works well, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please configure `Port forwarding` on your local network as this will allow you to access FastAPI application through the Minikube cluster.

Please follow the below kubectl command to establish port forwarding :

```
kubectl port-forward <pod-name> 8080:8080
```

The above command shows the below output.

```
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8080 → 8080
Forwarding from [::1]:8080 → 8080
```

Please use the `kubectl proxy` command to establish a direct connection from your local machine to your cluster’s API server to expose the Kubernetes API on a specific port.

```
kubectl proxy --port=6443
```

The above command will give you the following response:

```
Starting to serve on 127.0.0.1:6443
```

Please type the below information in the browser to view a list of all running Pods in the default namespace of your Kubernetes cluster.

```
http://localhost:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods
```

For more information please look into the [link](https://www.containiq.com/post/kubectl-port-forward) written by Lukonde Mwila.